# How to upgrade to latest version of Ubuntu software in 20.04

Tags: upgrade, software-installation, 20.04, software-center

Can I upgrade my Ubuntu software to the latest version in 20.04? Can I upgrade it to the latest version used in 20.10?

Comment: You can  upgrade to the versions that are in the 20.04 repositories by running `sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade`. If you try to update software to any other versions you risk to break the system. If you need 20.10 functionality you must upgrade to 20.10.

Comment: There is a tradeoff: 20.04 (LTS) has older software, but is supported for five *years*. 20.10 has newer software, but is supported for nine *months*, after which you must migrate to 21.04, then 21.10, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Update the list of available packages and their versions without upgrading them:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
2. Actually upgrade the installed packages while also removing redundant packages without causing data dependency issues, thanks to the "dist" in the command (which is better in my opinion):

   ```
   sudo apt dist-upgrade
   ```
3. Make sure that the `update-manager-core` package is installed:

   ```
   sudo apt install update-manager-core
   ```
4. Run:

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
   ```

   Change the value of `Prompt` from `lts` to `normal`. This is needed because 20.10 is not an LTS.
5. Upgrade from 20.04 to 20.10 (after upgrading all the packages):

   ```
   sudo do-release-upgrade
   ```