# Ubuntu 22.10 Beta on a Thinkpad L490 - Do I get system updates?

Tags: apt, updates, thinkpad, 22.10, beta

I just switched to Ubuntu on my Thinkpad L490.  Do I get system updates and if so, how?

Comment: i downloaded a developer iso

Comment: The *kinetic kudu* beta was provided long ago (refer https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/09/30/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-final-beta-released/) but was soon replaced with the 22.10 product (refer https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/10/20/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-released/) so check what you're actually using.  The current *development* release is *lunar* which is still in *alpha* with the beta not expected until [30 March 2023](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/lunar-lobster-release-schedule/27284) a few weeks before actual release.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upgrade to latest version of Ubuntu software in 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300602/how-to-upgrade-to-latest-version-of-ubuntu-software-in-20-04)

Comment: By "system updates", do you mean, for example, the driver updates that you are used to Lenovo Vantage providing in Windows?  IIRC, this includes occasional BIOS updates as well, right?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Ubuntu 22.10 beta. There is only a Ubuntu 22.10.

> Do I get system updates

Yes

> and how do i get them are my questions

Automatically by default. You will get a popup if there is any. See the "software updater" and "software sources" option in the menu.

You can force an update by doing

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt upgrade
```

yourself.

Comment: Or go in the "A"-program in the dock which has a "Check for updates" option.